# Create "Join a Personal Area Network" shortcut?

Tags: windows-8.1, bluetooth, shortcuts, pan

I am using Windows 8.1, When I right click the bluetooth icon on system traybar, there is `Join a Personal Area Network`

[image]

I would like to create that shortcut on my desktop, it looks like this, only showing the bluetooth device: 
[image]

On the path bar, it shows this place is `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers`, but when I go there, it always display all device instead of bluetooth device only :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### To Manually Create a "Bluetooth Devices" Shortcut

1. Right click an empty area of your desktop.
2. Click `New`.
3. Click `Shortcut`.

[image]

4. Set the location to `%windir%\explorer.exe shell:::{28803F59-3A75-4058-995F-4EE5503B023C}`
5. Click `Next`

[image]

6. Set the name to `Bluetooth Devices`
7. Click `Finish`

[image]

8. Right click the Bluetooth Devices shortcut
9. Click `Properties`

[image]

10. Click `Shortcut`
11. Click `Change Icon`

[image]

12. Set look for to `%SystemRoot%\system32\DevicePairingFolder.dll`.
13. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice.
14. Click the Bluetooth icon.
15. Click `OK` twice.

[image]

Source [Bluetooth Devices Shortcut - Create in Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/36102-bluetooth-devices-shortcut-create-windows-8-a.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but the shortcut is different from "Join a Personal Area Network”, here is the screenshot comparing: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3K7RF.png

Comment: @Bilo  In your screenshot which is the window you want to see and which window does the shortcut open?

Comment: The left one is what i want,  just like the screenshot in question,  but the shortcut open the right one,  which is searching available bluetooth device instead

Comment: @bilo Try using `explorer.exe localappdata%\Packages\windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Indexed\Settings\en-US\AAA_SettingsPagePCSystemBluetooth.settingcontent-ms` as the location. Replace `en-US` with your language code.

Comment: Hi, just tried but it is not working, it direct me to `Documents` this time

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any other suggestions. It seems from further google searching that what you actually want is a shortcut to `Bluetooth PAN`. Lots of people are asking but I couldn't find any other possible solutions apart from the above.